# wp.template for front end templating in WordPress how to write for each loop

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<# if ( data.trueValue ) { #>     <p> I am only output if <code>data.trueValue</code> is true.   <# } #>
```

As shown above iam able to write if condition outputting the result that is generated by wp.template() and my question is how can i write for each loop for the same if i want to loop through the data.

Comment: Finally Did it ... hope it help 
others
<# _.each( data, function(res, index) { #>
    <option value='{{res.field}}'>{{res.field}}</option>
<# }) #>

Comment: you should add your solution as the answer and accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Some like that

```
<div>
<?php foreach ($data as $value): ?>
    <?php if ($value): ?>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Syntax should be like this  <# foreach ($data as $value) { #>

Comment: I'm not understand You. What You want to do ?

Comment: Finally Did it ... hope it help 
others
<# _.each( data, function(res, index) { #>
    <option value='{{res.field}}'>{{res.field}}</option>
<# }) #>